# Right Parenthesis Expected

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

I have the below code:

```
public class CallOutForGet {

    HttpRequest request=new Httprequest();
http http=new http();
request.setEndPoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
request.setmethod('GET');

HttpResponse response=http.send(request);

if(response.getStatusCode()==200){

    Map<String,Object> results= (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

    List<object> animals=(List<object>)results.get('animals');
    System.debug('Received Animals************');
    for(object anim:animals){
        System.debug(anim);
    }
}

}
```

This error at line -  `request.setEndPoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');`  says expecting right parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is syntax error .You have to wrap your code inside a method .I only see class created with no method

```
public class CallOutForGet {

 public static void makeCall(){
  HttpRequest request=new Httprequest();
  http http=new http();
  request.setEndPoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
  request.setmethod('GET');

  HttpResponse response=http.send(request);
  if(response.getStatusCode()==200){
     Map<String,Object> results= (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    List<object> animals=(List<object>)results.get('animals');
    System.debug('Received Animals************');
    for(object anim:animals){
      System.debug(anim);
    }
  }

 }

}
```